# Read Computer Properties in C# + WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

How do I read system properties in WPF (I am programming in C# 4.0, VS2010) ? I want to display information about OS, CPU and GPU..

Comment: [Get System Info using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/nitinsysteminfo.aspx)

Comment: See [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/4b61e98e-568d-4175-bb7b-d7e33466d90b/)

Comment: VS2010 tells me that 'the type or namespace name `Forms` does not exist in the namespace `System.Windows`, which I think is crucial, isnt it?

Comment: You can use the forms class if you really force it, but please don't. We used to have to do this for the DataGrid and a few other controls when they were not included in the Framework and they caused a lot of trouble with incoherent bugs and memory consumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how far you want to go. If you want the most accurate data, use the System.Management class to call WMI Queries. However, if you really just want system info (static), then the System.Environment class (as suggested by Haris would be fine).

Win32_OperatingSystem has a lot of useful operating system data:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Win32_Processor will get you all the necessary processor information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If you are looking for live metrics you will need to use the Raw Performance Counters found in Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394317%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

There is plenty more you can do.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Environment Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) to get OS information and Processor Count